# Dynamic replacement of "string" in <object data="string" by javascript functions

Tags: javascript, function, object, parameters

How can I replace the string "http://www.ardtext.de/?page=303" in object data by Javascript function ard(). No problem for me to create it and use it in an form input but how to use it in **object data= ???? ...** ? The eventual purpose is to dynamically display url contents triggered by events.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ard() {
   var dqt = String.fromCharCode(34);
   var sender = "http://www.ardtext.de/?page=303";
   var tv_url = dqt.concat(sender, dqt);
   document.myobj.Ergebnisfeld.value = tv_url;
   return sender;
}
</script>

</HEAD>
<BODY onload="ard();" LANG="de-CH" TEXT="#990000" LINK="#0000cc" VLINK="#000066" BACKGROUND="Panasonic.jpg" DIR="LTR">
<TABLE CELLPADDING=2 CELLSPACING=2>
<TR>
    <TD>
    <P ALIGN=CENTER><IMG SRC="ARD.jpg" NAME="graphics3" ALT="ARD" ALIGN=BOTTOM WIDTH=80 HEIGHT=26 BORDER=0></TD>
etc.
…..
</TR>
</TABLE>
<form name="BruttoForm" action="">
<TABLE ID=TELETEXT BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=2 CELLSPACING=2 FRAME=VOID RULES=GROUPS STYLE="page-break-before: always">
    <TR>
    <TD><P>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</P></TD>
    <TD>
    <P>
        <object name="myobj" data="**http://www.ardtext.de/?page=303**" width="992" height="600">
        <param name="src" value="http://www.ardtext.de/?page=303">
        Ihr Browser kann das Objekt leider nicht anzeigen!
        </object>
    </P>
    </TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myobj = document.getElementById("myobj");
myobj.setAttribute("data", "**http://www.anotherurl.com**");
myobj.setAttribute("value", "http://www.anotherurl.com");
```

Comment: I succeeded like that with <script type="text/javascript">
function ard() {
 document.getElementsByName("myobj")[0].width = "992";
 document.getElementsByName("myobj")[0].height = "545";
 document.getElementsByName("myobj")[0].data = "http://www.ardtext.de/?page=303";
 document.getElementsByName("src")[0].value = "http://www.ardtext.de/?page=303";
}
</script>

Comment: <P><A href="javascript:ard()"><IMG SRC="ARD.jpg" etc. ...>  
  
<P>
 <object name="myobj" data="tv_noise.jpg" width="992" height="545">
     <param name="src" value="tv_noise.jpg">
     Cannot display!
   </object>
</P>  
  
BUT I MUST CLICK TWICE. WHY ? NO INFLUENDE USING <BODY onload="function();"

Comment: I don't understand what's going on in your last comment. Maybe you could make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: The only problem is that I have to run the function twice i.e. click twice.

Comment: 3 things I have to find out:
- simplify my code
- create a fiddle with it
- attach it here

This will take me some time.

Comment: Here is a fiddle behaving as describes above, i.e. I must click ARD twice.
First only the width and height values are set. Upon clicking again only the required  url gets imbeded, i.e. is displayed.


http://jsfiddle.net/aG647/2/

Comment: I found the answer given by Playmaker here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912925/reloading-an-html-element-with-a-javascript-function using:
       
    var container = document.getElementById("myobj");
    var content = container.innerHTML;
    container.innerHTML= content;

Comment: I was just looking in to this. Seems like others had problems changing the data attribute in '<object>'. Great if you found a solution!