# How can I update/refresh Google MDL elements that I add to my page dynamically?

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

I'm working with Google Material Design components which are stripped down for simplicity, then rendered more fully when the page is loaded. Simplified below to illustrate the issue:

**What shows in the index.html file**:

`<div class="switch"></div>`

**What renders to the DOM when the page is loaded**:

```
<div class="switch">
   <div class="switch_track"></div>
   <div class="switch_thumb"></div>
</div>
```

I am creating a drag and drop HTML editor and have template files for each component type. The template file for a switch is simply:

**switch.html**

`<div class="switch"></div>`

The problem is when I drag this to the canvas. jQuery looks at `switch.html` and renders `<div class="switch"></div>` to the DOM, but since it was dynamically added, it is not being "seen" by the scripts that added the additional track and thumb tags.

How can I fix this issue so that whenever the DOM is updated, it reruns any scripts? Ideally I would like to avoid touching any of the Material Design script files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912925/reloading-an-html-element-with-a-javascript-function.     Have you checked this post already?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I found the solution in [this MDL Github forum post](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/871) from MDL contributor [Jonathan Garbee](https://github.com/Garbee):

> The component handler [ **componentHandler.upgradeDom()** ] will handle upgrading everything if you just call it with no parameters.

So the pseudo-code of my solution would be:

```
 // Callback function of jquery-ui droppable element
 drop: function(event, ui) {
    // Add the element from it's template file
    $.get("templates/" + elem + ".html", function(data) {
      $("#canvas").append(data);

      // Expand all new MDL elements
      componentHandler.upgradeDom();
    });
 });
```

For future readers and users of the Material Design Lite (MDL) framework, you can also refresh dynamically added elements individually (instead of combing the entire DOM).

For example, `componentHandler.upgradeDom("mdl-menu")` will upgrade *only* `mdl-menu` elements.

[Further reading here.](http://www.getmdl.io/started/index.html#dynamic)

Comment: will this work with every mdl component? I tried it on an `mdl-textfield`, doesn't work as stated in here

Comment: How does this apply to the new MDC (Material Design Components) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  `componentHandler.upgradeDom();` for dynamically upgrade the element or use the following lines for downgrade the existing element and upgrade it again

Type 1:

```
   $(".data").find(".is-upgraded").each(function(){                 
       $(this).removeAttr("data-upgraded").find(".mdl-switch__ripple-container,.mdl-switch__track").remove();  //downgrade the existing upgraded elements
   });
    componentHandler.upgradeDom(); // upgrade the elements
```

Type 2:

```
 $(".data").html("{{content}}").promise().done(function(){                 
           componentHandler.upgradeDom(); // upgrade the newest elements 
 });
```