# Material Design Lite not fully working with Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, web-deployment, material-design-lite

I have a simple HTML template built with MDL.

When I place the template into Angular2 App. Elements' actions and clicks are not working

E.g : Showing `dropdowns` or clicking `tabs` etc are not working.

I cant see any errors in `Developer Console` and would like clarification on why this error is happening.

Comment: what is the error? put screenshot !

Comment: @micronyks Not giving any, I mentioned that above :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Material Design Lite tooltips not working with Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878521/material-design-lite-tooltips-not-working-with-angular-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `componentHandler.upgradeDom();` in `ngAfterViewInit()` and each time later when the DOM was modified:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  componentHandler.upgradeDom();
}
```

See also [Material Design Lite tooltips not working with Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878521/material-design-lite-tooltips-not-working-with-angular-2/35895400)

Comment: saying cannot find name `componentHandler`

Comment: In typescript. Just fixed that. It turned out I have to declare that `declare var componentHandler;`