# Material Design lite menu is not working in angular 2

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, angular, material-design

Trying to use material design lite menu But the menu never appears on the screen. While research found that the problem is Material Design Lite isn't designed to be used with dynamic pages.

Found the few solution but seems to not worked

[MDL not fully working with Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35981419/mdl-not-fully-working-with-angular2)

[Integrating Material Design Lite with Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421919/integrating-material-design-lite-with-angular2)

https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/4243

https://getmdl.io/started/#dynamic

Here is the app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
var componentHandler: any;
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'Home/HomePage',
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

HomePage.cstml

```
<button id="test1"
        class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
    <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
</button>

<ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
    for="test1">
    <li class="mdl-menu__item">Mobile App</li>
    <li class="mdl-menu__item">Customer Care</li>
    <li class="mdl-menu__item">Track Order</li>
    <li class="mdl-menu__item">Log in</li>
</ul>
```

While research found that I have to use **componentHandler.upgradeElement** or **componentHandler.upgradeDom();** or **componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();** . But exactly I, am not use know where I have to use it.

Can anyone please let me know how can I achieve the menu in angular 2

Comment: Did you try https://material.angular.io/?

Comment: No, I didn't I am using material design lite. Can you please let me know how can I fixed this issue

Comment: No I don't know the answer. MDL wasn't designed for Angular2 and trying to fit these two would be a massive work. I'm too lazy for that.

Answer (score 0):

This solve my problem for now

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var window: any;
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'Home/HomePage',

})
export class AppComponent {
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        window.componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
    }}
```