# Dynamically added checkbox don't look the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, material-design, material-design-lite

By adding a `mdl-checkbox` element to the HTML file, I get the following result:

[image]

```
<label id="check" class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
<input id="MdlCheckBox" type="checkbox" class="mdl-checkbox__input" value="0" />
<span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Check Me</span>
```

By adding the same code by injection the checkbox becomes plain:

[image]

```
var html = '<label id="check" class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect"><input id="MdlCheckBox" type="checkbox" class="mdl-checkbox__input" value="0" /><span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Check Me</span></label>';
$("#dynamic-checkbox").append(html);
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/idanmantzur/80mfmnw4/20/)

I have tried to use ready

```
$(function() {
  $("#dynamic-checkbox").append(html);
)};
```

No change.

Any recommended way to dynamically add `mdl` element?

Comment: You need to upgrade the DOM when you dynamically add a new element. Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32363511/how-can-i-update-refresh-google-mdl-elements-that-i-add-to-my-page-dynamically

Comment: you fiddle is not describing your problem

Comment: I can't see any problem with this Fiddle. Please, provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a section on dynamic added elements in the getting started guide

https://getmdl.io/started/index.html#dynamic

you hav to register the new element with

```
upgradeElement
```

Comment: Yes. `componentHandler.upgradeElements($('#dynamic-checkbox').get());`

Answer (score 0):

MDL dynamically add class to your component. When you add a component dynamically, you need to tell MDL to register to component in order to upgrade it. 
Your question is highly related to [How can I update/refresh Google MDL elements that I add to my page dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32363511/how-can-i-update-refresh-google-mdl-elements-that-i-add-to-my-page-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I dynamically add something I just upgrade everything:

```
function refreshMDL(){
    if(typeof componentHandler !=="undefined"){
        componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
    }
}
```

I run this function after I have dynamically added anything mdl dependent.